# On iOS, how to implement blocking or "being blocked" on a thread that produces data?

Tags: ios, multithreading, blocking, blockingqueue

If we need to implement a queue (being done by `NSMutableArray`), and we have `Producer` objects that add data to the queue.  There can be 1 producer or multiple producers.  And if the queue is full (at size of 100, for example), the thread should be "blocked" (waiting, until the queue is actually smaller size than 100 items).   (the same goes for taking away data from the queue: when it is empty, the getting of data is also blocked).

How can this "blocking" be implemented?  Right now I use a Mutex

```
@property (strong, atomic) NSLock *lock;
```

so that the count of the NSMutableArray is obtained and adding of item is done together (because the count can be 99, but when the item is added, the count can already be different).

But for the blocking effect, I actually check the count, and if 100, release the lock and sleep for 0.1 second, and then get the lock again and get the count, and repeat as above.

Is this a good way to implement the "blocking" behavior?  There seems to be another way to get a `canAddNowLock`, which is simply blocking by the `NSLock` mechanism, and when a queue item is removed, then release this `canAddNowLock`, but since there can be multiple data producers and data consumers, what if several producers are unblocked, or what if multiple consumers unlock `canAddNowLock` in a row and only 1 producer is unblocked (when in fact several producers should be unblocked)?  It just seem a more complicated design that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use NSCondition *condition
thread1:

```
[condition lock];
//check the queue is not full
[condition wait];//if already full, wait
//check again
//put something into queue
[condition unlock];
```

thread2:

```
[condition lock];
//check the queue is not empty
//get something from queue
[condition signal];
[condition unlock];
```

Comment: for thread1, so the `[condition wait]` and `[check again]` need to be in a loop?  (but since `signal` wakes up 1 thread (even when multiple threads are waiting, so maybe that will do the job already... that even the second check at `//check again` is not needed?)

Comment: for multiple thread, you can use [condition broadcast] to wake all of them. the second check is for safety, you can't be too careful for multithreading.

Comment: so if to be careful, doesn't the "check and wait" need to be in a loop then?  (but even if check a second time, if there is a bug, then even between the second check and the adding of data, there can already be some mal-effect already happened some where else...  (by the way I check 7 top iOS books including 2 cookbooks and none of them have `NSCondition` in the index section, but 2 official Apple iOS guides cover it)

Comment: if you always use this condition to protect your queue, you are holding the lock between [condition wait] and [condition unlock] so other threads can not manipulate the queue, it's safe enough. another reason that you should do double checks is that when you [condition wait], you actually release the lock, so anything can happen before you acquire it again. whether to use a loop depends on your app's logic, the code snippet I give you is just to inspire you.

Comment: I mean, what if the second check actually returns that the queue is full, then won't a `[condition wait]` need to be done again, and then a third check, and so on... and possible a fourth check and yet another wait, so doesn't that mean it needs to be in a loop?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little confused. Let's assume you have one producer thread and one consumer thread. In the producer, you second check will happen only after [condition wait] returns, which, in turn, will happen only after the consumer does [condition signal], which, in turn, means the queue is not full. If something peculiar really happens, i.e. your second check fails, then you need to do another [condition wait] to wait for the consumer consumes something.

Comment: yes, so for the fact that the "check" and the "wait" need to pair up and repeated, won't they go into a loop?